# Use cases diagram: an actor communicates something to another actor

Tags: uml, use-case

I have to build an use cases diagram and I am a bit confused about this specification.

> Each insurance company communicates to its headquarters, monthly, the progress of the activities (new clients, new policies, received payments).

The `insurance company` and the `headquarters` are both actors and they are associated to other use cases, for instance:

[image]

In my opionion, ***to communicate the progress of the activities*** is a functional requirement but I just haven't figured out how to express it using use cases diagram. Maybe something like this could be right:

[image]

but in this way I loose the information about who is alerted about the progress of the activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cases are used to specify the functionality of a particular information system. To determine which use cases are applicable for the communication between the insurance company and the headquarters, you need to know which system functionality is required. This is not clear from the text. I see four possibilities:

1. The communication is done without help of the system. In this case, you don't have any use cases.
2. The system must provide functionality to send the progress report, but the headquarters will not use the system to read that report. For example, the system will generate an e-mail, which will be read at headquarters using a regular e-mail application. In this case, you will have one use case 'Send progress report'.
3. The user representing the insurance company will send the report without help of the system, but by using his/her regular e-mail application to send the report to a specific e-mail address. Users representing headquarters however, use the system to read those reports. The system picks up the reports from the specific e-mail box and displays them to the users. In this case, you will have one use case 'Read progress report' or whatever.
4. The system is used on both ends. In this case, you will have two use cases, 'Send progress report' and 'Read progress report'.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply see that as two use cases. One is `Send progress activities` associated with `Insurance company`.  The other is `Evaluate report` associated with `Headquarter`. If a communication runs outside the system you don't need to capture it. But part of a business analysis is to find out such off-track communications and bind them to the system under consideration.

N.B. Use predicate/subject[/object] like `Handle offers` and not `Handles offers`.